# How can I fetch 10 newest objects and sort it descending [ios,coredata]

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, fetch

I can fetch the 10 newest by sort descriptorWithKey "ms_createdAt" ascending NO, next I want to rearrange this 10 objects to ascending:YES

Please tell me how

this is my code so far

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setFetchLimit:10];
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = delegate.managedObjectContext;

ChatInfo *chat = [ChatInfo getInstance];

fetchRequest.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AudioHistory" inManagedObjectContext:context];

// fectch max date first
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uploadedby == %@ && sentto == %@) || (uploadedby == %@ && sentto == %@)", chat.userid, chat.friendid, chat.friendid, chat.userid];

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ms_createdAt" ascending:NO]];

NSFetchedResultsController *firstFetchedResult =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];

NSArray *maxDate = firstFetchedResult.fetchedObjects;

NSLog(@"Max Date :%@", maxDate);
// search by channels id

fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(uploadedby == %@ && sentto == %@) || (uploadedby == %@ && sentto == %@)", chat.userid, chat.friendid, chat.friendid, chat.userid];

// sort by item text
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ms_createdAt" ascending:YES]];


NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                    managedObjectContext:maxDate sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                               cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
//self.fetchedResultsController = firstFetchedResult;

_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

still get an error on second fetchedResultsController

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking ; you want the 10 newest objects of your fetch request?

Comment: @Zil No, I want the newest date object that I don't know how much objects store that date. Example newest date is 2015-3-5, and 5 objects store this date, I want to fetch all 5 objects. or maybe the newest date is today and 10 objects store 'today' for key date, I want it all 10 date. do you understand? so sorry for my English

Comment: I think you will need to do two fetches: first, fetch (with order descending and fetchLimit set to 1) the object with the latest date.  Get that date and remove any time element (remembering to adjust for time zone if necessary).  Call that `maxDate`.  Then, for the fetch underlying the fetchedResultsController, build a new predicate with "ms_createdAt > %@", maxDate (AND all your other predicate criteria).  And sort this ascending.

Comment: @pbasdf
I got some problem I can get the object from first fetch

maxDate always return null but my table view always show the right result too.

Comment: @pbasdf
I add this code after fetch the object (with limit 1 and descending)

    NSManagedObjectContext *maxDate = [firstFetchedResult objectAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
    NSLog(@"Max Date :%@", maxDate); // this show null

Comment: Can you update the question with the full code?  Thanks

Comment: @pbasdf It's updated. thank you so much, thanks for your time.

Comment: Your question has changed slightly; do you actually want the most recent 10, or all the items for the most recent date?

Comment: @pbasdf I changed my target.

i got it, just add this code

fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ms_createdAt" ascending:YES]]; 

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    
    if (objects.count >= 10) {

        [fetchRequest setFetchOffset:objects.count-10];
        
    }

Comment: Yes, exactly what I was going to suggest.